# Call to undefined method stdClass::full_name()

Tags: php

I am trying to chain static functions, so I can use different viariables inside one another.

I have 2 functions like so:

```
<?php
namespace Adspace\Model;

use Adspace\Core\Request;
use Adspace\Core\DatabaseFactory;
use Adspace\Core\Alert;
use Adspace\Core\Session;
use Adspace\Core\Filter;

Class AccountModel
{
    // the info to store user info in
    public static $userInfo;

    public static function getuser()
    {
        // the user's info
        static::$userInfo = SELF::user_details(null, Session::get('user_id'));

        return static::$userInfo;
    }

    public static function full_name()
    {
        // return the full name
        return ucwords(Filter::XSSFilter($userInfo->user_firstname).' '. Filter::XSSFilter($userInfo->user_surname));
    }
```

I am trying to use that like so:

```
<?php echo \Adspace\Model\AccountModel::getuser()->full_name(); ?>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   stdClass::full_name() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\application\view\templates\back\header.php:48

What is causing this issue, and how would I fix this?

Comment: You should probably first read an OOP tutorial. I have no idea why you try to mix static and instance-specific variables.

Comment: no need to use static::  use self:: instead, and are you sure user_details is returning object  from type user info as you are expecting ?

Comment: @Diab - static vs self is far from the biggest problem in this script. There's a lack of understanding of basic OOP and scopes.

Comment: I tried returning SELF, before trying the above approcach, but always got:  Call to a member function full_name() on null